# Using advanced filters in columns for cells with two or more values

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the link below you see an example of the data I'm dealing with. It's data on joint ventures between pharmaceutical companies taken from the SDC Platinum database. The reason I'm reaching my limits with advanced filters is because each cell contains multiple values and they are all formatted like this: String, followed by linebreak, then another string.

For the 'Participant Ultimate Parent Nation' column, I'd like to only include deals that have all their parties IN Europe. I do have a list of all nations that are considered Europe, but don't know how I could incorporate that into an advanced filter.

For the 'Participant Ultimate Parent Primary SIC Code' column, I'd like to have each cell include at least one of these SIC Codes (2833, 2834, 2835, 2836).

Line 8 is a line that would be included with both filters applied.

I'd be very grateful if you're able to help me.

[image: Data Example]

Comment: You're going to almost certainly want to break out those cells from "merged data".  What have you tried? I assume those are line breaks after each entry in the same cell?

Comment: What do you mean by breaking out those cells from merged data? Yes, those are linebreaks after each entry in the same cell. Here's an [Expanded view] (https://imgur.com/ZXeoXGV) of that same example above.

Comment: Make your life a lot easier; recreate the table such that each line has data about ONE "participant" (or whatever, generally) with corresponding sub-related pieces of info in columns to the right of it. Even a two-part "database" with items (main list/database) and sub-items (sub-list/item database) is more workable than the mix I see here.

Comment: I found lots of discrepancies in your data set like, as @Hannu suggested data are in merged cell, like in row 1 Japan & Spain. Other is the Code, like 2834 is for the Japan, United States, Spain, Denmark. Now when you filter, Excel get confused since Japan is Asian country and US, Spain are European nations. Somewhere USA got 8082,, is quite confusion. So better clear to me, if the existing one is correct or not I'll show how to use multiple criteria.

Comment: @RajeshS USA got the code 8082 on line 10, because the company that is from the USA works in the industry that has the SIC code 8082. The numbers are not unique to the countries. Look at the screenshot I posted in my previous comment for a more complete picture. How would you filter with multiple criteria in that case?

Comment: @TIV,, the code you want to use as criteria are 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836 & second is Europe, in this case Excel will filter both from Asia and Europe because 2834 is for Japan and USA also and more. As you said codes are not unique in this case if I use all 4 codes and Europe in all adjacent cells with Unique Records option, excel will display Denmark, Spain & Sweden along with 2834 only from Europe. Remember I'm using few of the records. Now tell me will this work for you?